# MultiMap comparison object with key and value pair

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I want to write a comparison object for my multimap which is sorted according to keys and if two keys are equal then according to their value.
Problem I am facing is that that inbuilt library of multimap passes only key in comparison object and not value.

Please, can someone help me how can I do this..

Comment: Perhaps [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) might help?

Comment: Perhaps a `multiset<pair<T1, T2>>` or even `set<pair<T1, T2>>` would be better choices.

Comment: "The order of the key-value pairs whose keys compare equivalent is the order of insertion and does not change. (since C++11)" Can't I sort them by value it means?

Comment: Yes, It can be done that way but I need to change lot of stuffs then. Is there no way to do this like that only? @NickyC

Comment: @AnushiMaheshwari It all depends on the function used to compare the "keys". Have you tried providing your *own* comparison function? The reference should help you figure out how to do that.

Comment: I am stuck at writing one such.Please, can you help and provide one?

Comment: If you want to sort it by "value", that "value" is by definition a key or a part of a key, not just a "value". Choosing `multimap` or `map` is therefore illogical.

Comment: Additionally: Within maps, the key must be immutable, the value *not*. So you *can* change the value, but no (automatic) re-sorting will occur then! That's just how `std::map`s work by design...

Comment: Okay, then I need to switch to sets and rewrite whole code. :(

Comment: When you do, define a type alias and use that throughout, or alternatively `auto`. Then you will see how similar the `set` and `map` interfaces are